# Transparent backcolor of label

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I am making a simple form (C#) and set it transparent by `transparencyKey` and `BackColor` equal to `White`. But my text in the `Labels`, `GroupBoxes` and `Buttons` are still having a little background in white (set `BackColor` equal to `Transparent`).

Here is result:

[image]

I want to make the white disappears. Look like in this clip [in 5:07](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0qwzU9TrUw&t=5m7s)

Comment: Try disabling anti-aliasing when you draw text

Comment: @Micky that will make text look pretty bad.

Comment: Maybe see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378464/c-sharp-winforms-transparency-issue-i-going-crazy-with-it

Comment: I have turned Clear Type off in the past to solve this very same issue.

Comment: I did not see Clear Type in Properties GUI of label

Comment: It is under the operating system's display properties

Comment: @Cyral agreed but it's not possible to have transparency with anti-aliasing in WinForms. The latter is causing the artefacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want anti-aliasing, you won't be able to get it with TransparencyKey, pretty much by definition. TransparencyKey picks a *single* color, and any pixels of that color become totally transparent. Anti-aliasing uses various shades to simulate smoothed edges; those shades don't match the single color you're making transparent, so those pixels will be opaque, which is exactly what we see in your screenshot.

You need to use what Windows refers to as a "layered window". There are two kinds of layered windows; there's the kind that uses TransparencyKey (which WinForms supports, but won't suit your needs), and the kind that lets you specify a transparency value for each individual pixel of your window (which it looks like WinForms does not support out of the box).

My recommendation would be to **use WPF instead of WinForms.** WinForms is ancient technology, and really isn't suited to the kind of UI effects you're trying to create here. It doesn't even have good support for semitransparent controls *within* a form, much less per-pixel alpha for the form itself based on its contents.

WPF *can* do per-pixel transparency out of the box. Set your window's `WindowStyle` to `None` and `AllowsTransparency` to `true`, and then you can use all the transparency effects you want. Set your window's background color to `Transparent` (if you want clicks on empty areas to still go to your window) or `{x:None}` (if you want clicks on empty areas to go to the window underneath yours) or a semi-transparent brush; layer semitransparent controls or ARGB bitmaps on top of each other; it'll all look great.

If you really want to use WinForms for some reason, I'm guessing you'll have a *lot* of work ahead of you. I'd suggest Googling for "WinForms layered window" and brushing up on your P/Invoke.

Answer (score -1):

You should set your BackColor as transparent.

Comment: Which backColor, ctg30?

Comment: You may want to describe your solution in more details?

Comment: This answer is so thin, it's virtually transparent itself.